# In LDS Doctrine, is the Resurrection a Priesthood Ordinance?

Tags: lds, resurrection

I have heard some LDS members say that the act of resurrection is actually a Priesthood ordinance. Is there scripture or words from LDS leaders stating such? Or is this an assumption?

Comment: Welcom to Christianity.SE!  When you get a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brigham Young spoke of it as a Priesthood ordinance:

> It is supposed by this people that we have all the ordinances in our possession for life and salvation, and exaltation, and that we are administering in these ordinances. This is not the case. We are in possession of all the ordinances that can be administered in the flesh; but there are other ordinances and administrations that must be administered beyond this world. I know you would ask what they are. I will mention one.
>
> We have not, neither can we receive here, the ordinance and the keys of the resurrection. They will be given to those who have passed off this stage of action and have received their bodies again, as many have already done and many more will. They will be ordained, by those who hold the keys of the resurrection, to go forth and resurrect the Saints, just as we receive the ordinance of baptism, then the keys of authority to baptize others for the remission of their sins. This is one of the ordinances we can not receive here, and there are many more.
>
> -- *Journal of Discourses,* 15:137-38

While Latter-Day Saints do not hold the *Journal of Discourses* to be authoritative scripture, this is the word of a prophet on the matter, and President Spencer W. Kimball considered this talk authoritative enough to [quote and comment upon in General Conference.](https://www.lds.org/general-conference/1977/04/our-great-potential?lang=eng)

Comment: This is a good answer, and the doctrine is reflected in the precursor to a Temple sealing when husband brings wife through the veil, symbolizing that if both are righteous and the marriage sealed by the Holy Spirit of Promise, he will perform the resurrection ordinance on behalf of his wife.  However, as BY states, it's not an ordinance of this estate, and so there isn't a manual that discusses its performance and, not surprisingly, we don't worry about it.